# Android remote build system - install automation

Tags: android, automation, installation

I've put together a remote build system for Android using Ant on a Windows machine and I'm trying to figure out my options for an automated installer in order to deploy the build system to one of my client's machines.

The installer should be able to download Android SDK, Ant, GIT, launch and configure Android's install manager, configure system settings such as the PATH environment variable, configure GIT, etc.

And there is a slight possibility that I'll have to use a Linux client machine some time in the future.

Apart from writing such a software in, say, Qt, I don't see how to do this. Any help/ideas are very appreciated.

Comment: if its just one or two clients you would be better off using something like remote desktop. There are literally a thousand things that can go wrong during the whole cycle. Automating this process wont be easy.

Comment: Ok, but what would be my options, in general, aside from writing such an installer from scratch?